# How would I write a mysql query that could be divided into 5 html lists of equal length

Tags: php, html

I'm fairly new to php. I have some items in a database table and I would like to display them in 5 unordered lists of equal length.

For example:

```
<ul>
  <li>row 1</li>
  <li>row 2</li>
  <li>row 3</li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>row 4</li>
  <li>row 5</li>
  <li>row 6</li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>row 7</li>
  <li>row 8</li>
  <li>row 9</li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>row 10</li>
  <li>row 11</li>
  <li>row 12</li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>row 13</li>
  <li>row 14</li>
  <li>row 15</li>
</ul>
```

I've looked around, but haven't come up with an answer on my own. I know how to get the rows from the database, but I'm having a mental block on how to divide the results into 5 groups.

Any and all help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Dont! Make the split in the PHP code, thats easy

Comment: Also, what woudl happen if you were to get 30 results from your query, what woudl you do then? 6 items in a group? Or 15 groups of 3

Comment: This is not really a mysql question, but a php / html one, since you want to amke the results of a mysql query appear in a specific way.

Comment: One of the most important skills to learn in programming is to break your problem down. The code that divides a list into 5 equal parts doesn't need to know anything about where that list came from.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Here's the code that gives the results I was looking for:

```
        $query = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM itemTable");
        $query->execute();
        while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
            $rows[] = $row;
        }

        $lists = array_chunk($rows, ceil(count($rows)/5)));

        foreach ($lists as $column) {
            echo '<ul>';
                foreach ($column as $item) {
                $filename = $item['file_name'];
                    echo '<li>'.$filename.'</li>';
                }
            echo '</ul>';
        }
```

Thanks for pointing me away from mysql.